# Aplicación en Android TCP servidor cliente solo envía un mensaje

Tags: android, kotlin, hilos, tcp

tengo un problema con una Aplicación en Android TCP servidor cliente. Cuando envío el mensaje al servidor solo me muestra el primer mensaje que envió los otros no. Los tengo en  proyectos separado y los ejecuto en el simulador móvil.
Si creo un nuevo Socket por cada vez que hago un click para enviar un mensaje el servidor recibe todos los mensajes.
Mi intención de crear proyectos separados es porque necesito crear varios clientes.

**SERVER CLASS**

```
class Server(private val myHandler: Handler) : Thread() {

    private lateinit var serverSocket: ServerSocket
    private lateinit var ois: ObjectInputStream
    private lateinit var socket: Socket

    init {
        start()
    }

    override fun run() {
        try {
            serverSocket = ServerSocket()
            serverSocket.reuseAddress = true
            serverSocket.bind(InetSocketAddress(9000))
            while (true) {
                socket = serverSocket.accept()
                val clientMessage = Message.obtain()
                ois = ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream())
                val stringMessage = ois.readObject() as String
                clientMessage.obj = stringMessage
                myHandler.sendMessage(clientMessage)
                //ois.close()
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            val msg = Message.obtain()
            msg.obj = e.message
            myHandler.sendMessage(msg)
        } catch (e: ClassNotFoundException) {
            val msg = Message.obtain()
            msg.obj = e.message
            myHandler.sendMessage(msg)
        }
    }
}
```

**Server MAIN**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    var messageList = arrayListOf<String>()
    var myAdapter: ArrayAdapter<String>? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        myAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, messageList)
        binding.listServidor.adapter = myAdapter
        binding.btnConnect.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "SERVIDOR INICIADO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            Server(myHandler)
        }
        setContentView(binding.root)

    }
    private val myHandler: Handler = object : Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        override fun handleMessage(status: Message) {
            val myMessage = status.obj?.toString()
            myMessage?.let {
                messageList.add(it)
            }
            myAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
}
```

**CLIENT CLASS**

````
class Client : Thread() {

    private lateinit var socket: Socket
    private lateinit var outputStream: ObjectOutputStream

    init {
        start()
    }

    override fun run() {
        try {
            socket = Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost().hostAddress,9000)
            socket.reuseAddress = true
            socket.keepAlive = true
            outputStream = ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())
        } catch (e: UnknownHostException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    fun sendMessage(context: Context, message: String) {
        if (this::outputStream.isInitialized){
            try {
                outputStream.writeObject(message)
                outputStream.flush()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "OUTPUT IS NOT CREATED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```**CLIENT MAIN**
````

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

private var client1: Client? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val policy = ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    client1 = Client()
    binding.apply {
        btnSendMessage.setOnClickListener {
            client1?.sendMessage(applicationContext, 
             etClient.text.toString())
            etClient.text?.clear()
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Que error se imprime en el LogCat?

Comment: No me da ningún error